# How to get input field value from a form using preg_match()

Tags: php, regex, curl, preg-match

I am not a expert in this field so please help me out and spare my ignorance if any.
I am trying to curl through a page and want to get value of the hidden `<input>` field. I am not familiar with regexp. my code is as below:

```
       $page = curl_exec($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);

function parse_form_fields($page, $username, $password){
    preg_match("/<input id=\"signuptoken\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"(.+?)\" name=\"signuptoken\"/", $page, $m);

    $captchatoken = $m[1];

    $parameters[] = "newaccounttoken=" . urlencode($captchatoken);
}
```

the form field is as below:

```
<input id="signuptoken" type="hidden" value="03AHJ_Vuv2ts6ev2LltAkZB91vjD6k-BsW3286bTC9QZYZLSHQUMNDQJFUaNmAQMAYb9FDhIkOFzAisafasfsTZuv_pl5KvkYNfsGUPcOAEX5YPlMaMOi7MZJq4ky0v_GyM60SmMgjPrtfZSJYE0hqw--GsfsafasmER0Sksr6OAvnLnBVAMsKcCi7uM" name="signuptoken">
```

I want to get the value out for this input field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're better off using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). For example:

```
$html = '<input id="signuptoken" type="hidden" value="03AHJ_Vuv2ts6ev2LltAkZB91vjD6k-BsW3286bTC9QZYZLSHQUMNDQJFUaNmAQMAYb9FDhIkOFzAisafasfsTZuv_pl5KvkYNfsGUPcOAEX5YPlMaMOi7MZJq4ky0v_GyM60SmMgjPrtfZSJYE0hqw--GsfsafasmER0Sksr6OAvnLnBVAMsKcCi7uM" name="signuptoken">';
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$signuptoken = $dom->getElementById("signuptoken");
echo $signuptoken->getAttribute('value');
```

Comment: @DeepakVerma glad to know it did. Be sure to accept an answer so others with the same problem will know what solution worked.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you to find the value:

```
<?php
$input  = '<input id="signuptoken" type="hidden" value="03AHJ_Vuv2ts6ev2LltAkZB91vjD6k-BsW3286bTC9QZYZLSHQUMNDQJFUaNmAQMAYb9FDhIkOFzAisafasfsTZuv_pl5KvkYNfsGUPcOAEX5YPlMaMOi7MZJq4ky0v_GyM60SmMgjPrtfZSJYE0hqw--GsfsafasmER0Sksr6OAvnLnBVAMsKcCi7uM" name="signuptoken">';

$result = preg_match('/<input id="signuptoken" type="hidden" value="(.*?)"/', $input, $matches);
if(!$result){
    // Could not find input
} else {
    // Input value found
    echo 'Value: '.$matches[1];
}
```

Parsing HTML with regex is not exactly resilient, however, as simply changing the order of the `id` and the `type` in the example `input` tag will break the scraper. If you're sure the HTML will never change, that shouldn't be an issue, but just be aware a DOM parser may be more useful in some cases.

Comment: Thanks Adam, It works for the variable (i.e. $input) I want to find it in the webpage I curled through ($page = curl_exec($ch);)

Comment: @DeepakVerma You can actually use `[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)` to load a URL if your PHP installation is set up properly (which it probably is) – just replace `$input = '...';` in the example with `$input = file_get_contents('[your url]');` and that should work

Comment: what is the Regular Expressions for <textarea> , i tried the above one but it's not work

Answer (score 0):

Don't use things like `value=\"(.+?)\"`, you may have a lot of troubles with them in some bad-formated HTML. Use something more limiting like `value=\"([^\">]+?)\"`. The difference is that `.` matches a lot more entities, than `[^">]`, which will always end on tag close or quote close.

The problem in your case might be the lack of multi-line match modifier *s*, try `preg_match('/<input id="signuptoken" type="hidden" value="(.*?)"/s', $page, $m);`.

Other than that, I'll second that, use DOM.

Also, save page HTML into file and test your RegEx on local file instead of calling the page every time.